# How can I pre-ready the RecycledViewPool of RecyclerView to avoid initial jerks in scrolling?

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview

I've a RecyclerView with 3 different ViewTypes in it. If I scroll the list then for initial few items it shows a jerking/shivering during scroll. When RecycledViewPool is filled to max limit then as views are reused so scrolling becomes smooth. So, I was thinking of making the RecycledViewPool pre-ready. I tried creating some view holders and added in the pool before the user starts scrolling. But the pool shows 0 count for manual inserted views. It shows correct count when RecyclerView itself adds view to the pool on scroll. I'm using following method to achieve this. Is it good idea? or there is some more accurate solution for this?

```
   private void addDummyRecycledViews() {
                  int size = demoAdaptor.getList().size() > 7 ? 7 : demoAdaptor.getList().size();

                RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool recycledViewPool = recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool();
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    BaseViewHolder viewHolder = null;
                    int viewType = demoAdaptor.getItemViewType(i);
                    int recycledViewCount = recycledViewPool.getRecycledViewCount(viewType);
                    AppLogger.d("usm_test_adapter_dummy", "viewType= "+viewType+" ,recycledViewCount= "+recycledViewCount);
                    switch (viewType) {
                        case VIEW_TYPE_SIMPLE:
                            AppLogger.d("usm_test_adapter_dummy", "generate VIEW_TYPE_SIMPLE");
                            viewHolder = demoAdaptor.createSimpleItemViewHolder(recyclerView);
                            break;
                        case VIEW_TYPE_SEARCH:
                            AppLogger.d("usm_test_adapter_dummy", "generate VIEW_TYPE_SEARCH");
                            viewHolder = demoAdaptor.createSearchItemViewHolder(recyclerView);
                            break;
                        case VIEW_TYPE_VIDEO:
                            AppLogger.d("usm_test_adapter_dummy", "generate VIEW_TYPE_VIDEO");
                            viewHolder = demoAdaptor.createVideoItemViewHolder(recyclerView);
                            break;
                    }
                    if (viewHolder != null) {
                        demoAdaptor.onBindViewHolder(viewHolder, i);
                        recycledViewPool.putRecycledView(viewHolder);
                    }

                }
                recyclerView.setRecycledViewPool(recycledViewPool);

        }
```

Comment: did you find any solution for this problem?

Comment: no but keeping view hierarchy simple added some improvement, please check "Show overdraw areas" in developer mode as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is doable with some tweaks to your code. The key points are:

1. Increase the RecycledViewPool's max recycled views to fit the number you want.
2. Call the correct method to create view holders: Call `Adapter.createViewHolder()`, **not** `Adapter.onCreateViewHolder()`. This is needed because one method sets `ViewHolder.mItemViewType` and the other does not.
3. Insert the correct number of ViewHolders into the pool, remembering that the initially visible items may consume ViewHolders.

For example, if you expect 6 items visible on screen initially, and you want an additional 4 in the pool, you can set a max of 10 recycled views.

You could do this in `onCreateView()`:

```java
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // ... create your views ...
    
    // initialize some recycled views for smoother initial scrolling
    final int EXPECTED_VISIBLE_INITIALLY = 6;
    final int EXTRA_IN_POOL = 4;
    final int POOL_SIZE = EXPECTED_VISIBLE_INITIALLY + EXTRA_IN_POOL;
    recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(VIEW_TYPE_VIDEO, POOL_SIZE);
    for (int i = 0; i < POOL_SIZE; i++) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = adapter.createViewHolder(recyclerView, VIEW_TYPE_VIDEO);
        recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().putRecycledView(viewHolder);
    }

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without knowing the parent RecyclerView in advance? Seeing as how multiple RecyclerViews can share one pool and thus ViewHolders don't necessarily belong forever to the parent they were created on, is it possible to somehow *not* give a parent during this pre-ready (or do I need a hidden dummy RecyclerView somewhere)?